# Colocar um array dentro de outro

Tags: php, array

Como eu faço para adicionar o array "favoritas" ao array "cores"?

```
$a1['cores']=array("vermelho","amerelo","preto");
$a2['favoritas']=array("amerelo","preto");
```

Eu já tentei com array_merge

```
array_merge($a1,$a2);
print_r($a1);
```

com array_push

```
array_push($a1,$a2);
print_r($a1);
```

mas não vai.

O resultado que eu quero.

```
  Array ( [cores] => Array ( [0] => vermelho [1] => amerelo [2] => preto [favoritas] => Array ( [0] => amerelo [1] => preto ) ) )
```

Comment: Precisa declarar 2 Arrays mesmo? Se fizer 
`$a['cores']=array("vermelho","amerelo","preto");`
`$a['favoritas']=array("amerelo","preto");`
Vai ter o resultado, a menos que precise das duas listas mesmo.

Comment: Infelizmente precisa. :(

Comment: Cria um terceiro, `a3['cores'] = a1; a3['favoritas'] = a2;`

Comment: Rogério, tem algo errado aí. O resultado foi Array ( [cores] => Array ( [cores] => Array ( [0] => vermelho [1] => amerelo [2] => preto ) ) [favoritas] => Array ( [favoritas] => Array ( [0] => amerelo [1] => preto ) ) )

Comment: Pq você declara o a1 e o a2 com esses índices.. Agora ficou fácil.. hehe

Comment: Desculpa, eu não entendi. mas sua resposta não condiz com minha pergunta. Eu coloquei a sua resposta para rodar e não é igual(ou parecida) com o que eu quero.

Answer (score 0):

bom dia um modo bem simples de fazer isso e

```
$a1['cores']=["vermelho","amerelo","preto"];
$a2['favoritas']=["amerelo","preto"];
$a2['favoritas']['cores']=$a1['cores'];
```

Comment: clone, eu vou marcar como resolvido mas vc mudou a estrutura do código que eu coloquei e isso não é muito legal para pessoas que não podem mudar, no meu caso eu posso mudar e por isso eu consegui resolver o problema. só altera o código para:                            $a1['cores']['favoritas']=$a2['favoritas']; print_r($a1);

Answer (score 0):

Crie um com os dois arrays   [veja no ideone](https://ideone.com/vkTNhU)

```
$a1['cores']=array("vermelho","amerelo","preto");
 
$a2['favoritas']=array("amerelo","preto");
 
$resultQueEuQuero = array($a1, $a2);
print_r($resultQueEuQuero);
die;
```

Comment: Boa tarde, leo."Favoritas" tem que ficar dentro de cores. mas eu já resolvi o problema. obrigado pela contribuição.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o que esta procurando é isso. Lembre que o `array_merge` não tem referencia com o array passado, este método tem o retorno com o array mergeado.

```php
$a1['cores']=array("vermelho","amerelo","preto");
$a2['favoritas']=array("amerelo","preto");
$a1 = array_merge($a1['cores'], $a2);
```